# cannot convert from threading task<bool> to system action

Tags: c#, task, threadpool

i have problem to run task in button
Problem is : cannot convert from threading.task.task to system action
i marked the line in the button

```
         private async void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
```

```
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty( txtProxy.Text) || lstviewcomp.Items.Count==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please uploads files");
            return;
        }
        proxies = txtProxy.Text.Split('\n');
        proxycount = proxies.Length;
        foreach (string item in lstviewcomp.Items)
        {
            proxycount++;
            if (proxyCounter> proxycount)
            {
                proxyCounter = 0;
            }
            ProxyInfo = proxies[proxyCounter].Split(',');
            var result = await Task.Run( MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", "")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();// Problem in this line 


            // proxyCounter++;
        }
    }
```

public async Task MainAsync(string instausername,string pass,string proxyip,string proxyport,string proxyusername,string proxypass)
        {
            try
            {
                // create user session data and provide login details
                var userSession = new UserSessionData
                {
                    UserName = instausername,
                    Password = pass
                };
                // create proxy handeler
                var httpHndler = new HttpClientHandler();
                IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyip,Convert.ToInt32(proxyport));
                proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyusername, proxypass);
                httpHndler.Proxy = proxy;
                // create new InstaApi instance using Builder
                _instaApi = new InstaApiBuilder()
                    .SetUser(userSession)
                    .UseHttpClientHandler(httpHndler)
                    .UseLogger(logger: new DebugFileLogger()) // use logger for requests and debug messages
                    .SetRequestDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) // set delay between requests
                    .Build();

`// login
            txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + $"Logging in as {userSession.UserName}"+" At "+DateTime.Now+"\n";
            var logInResult = await _instaApi.LoginAsync();
            if (!logInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + $"Unable to login: {logInResult.Info.Message}" + " At " + DateTime.Now + "\n";

            }
            else
            {
                txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + $"Logging in success : {userSession.UserName}" + " At " + DateTime.Now + "\n";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            var logoutResult = Task.Run(() => _instaApi.LogoutAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (logoutResult.Succeeded) txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + "Logout sucess \n";

        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: `Task.Run(() => MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", ""))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public async Task MainAsync
```

should be changed to

```
public async Task<bool> MainAsync
```

And then instead of

```
var result = await Task.Run( MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", "")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

you can use

```
var result = await MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", "");
```

Also you need to use `async` in the following line too:

```
var logoutResult = Task.Run(() => _instaApi.LogoutAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Becomes:

```
var logoutResult = await _instaApi.LogoutAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Run` take `Func<Task>` or `Action` (of course you can pass additionaly `CancellationToken`). So for your case you need pass a function that returns a Task and doesn't try to await a `void` (I hope you are remember that you cannot await a `void`). Just get the result of task:

```
Task.Run(() => MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", "")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

You can directly wait the task instead of code above:

```
Task.Run(() => MainAsync("", "", "", "", "", "")).Wait();
```

But if you want to continue your workflow asynchronously by task' result your `MainAsync` should returns a `Task<bool>` as pointed out in @Olexiy Sadovnikov answer and await the returned task.